# Cannot resolve method 'assertThat(int)'

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, hamcrest

I'm following the [Test Navigation docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing#java) that has the following test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class TitleScreenTestJava {

    @Test
    public void testNavigationToInGameScreen() {

        // Create a TestNavHostController
        TestNavHostController navController = new TestNavHostController(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext());

        // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the TitleScreen
        FragmentScenario<TitleScreen> titleScenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(TitleScreen.class);

        titleScenario.onFragment(fragment ->
                // Set the graph on the TestNavHostController
                navController.setGraph(R.navigation.trivia);

                // Make the NavController available via the findNavController() APIs
                Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
        );

        // Verify that performing a click changes the NavController’s state
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.play_btn)).perform(ViewActions.click());
        assertThat(navController.currentDestination.id).isEqualTo(R.id.in_game);
    }
}
```

First of all, this gives

> Cannot resolve symbol 'currentDestination'

After some digging, I find `getCurrentDestination()`. I also have to change `id` to `getId()` to fix a similar error.

Then I get

> Cannot resolve method 'assertThat(int)'

What version of `assertThat()` should I import? I found [2 versions](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(java.lang.String,%20T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) [in JUnit](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)), but neither takes only one parameter. Besides both are deprecated. [`org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.html) has 3 versions of `assertThat()`, but again, none take a single `int` or `Integer` parameter. So where do I find the right version of `assertThat()`?

Beyond that, what am I missing here with all these changes I seem to be needed to fix the example from the official android docs? Or is this example broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) library.

[Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.22.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

> AssertJ is a Java library that provides a rich set of assertions and
> truly helpful error messages, improves test code readability, and is
> designed to be super easy to use

```java
// basic assertions
assertThat(frodo.getName()).isEqualTo("Frodo");
assertThat(frodo).isNotEqualTo(sauron);
```

See [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html) [assertThat(int)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThat(int))

**Update:**

I have reviewed more deeply android docs.
Looks like [Truth library](https://truth.dev/) ([Maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.truth/truth)) is used.

Truth is the preferred library according to android docs and recommendations. It is part of Jetpack [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/test#truth_extensions_150_2).

Jetpack is a suite of libraries to help developers follow best practices, reduce boilerplate code, and write code that works consistently across Android versions and devices so that developers can focus on the code they care about.

See [example of test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests#java) with correct imports. [Git](https://github.com/android/testing-samples/blob/main/unit/BasicUnitAndroidTest/app/build.gradle) 
Documentation about [assertThat(Integer)](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.truth/truth/latest/com/google/common/truth/Truth.html)

[AndroidX is an extension of Truth](https://truth.dev/extension)

> Other extensions that are not part
> of the Truth project itself include:
>
> - AndroidX Test for testing Android types, like Intent

[Setup project with AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/test-setup)

```
    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$testJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:truth:$truthVersion"
```

**Truth vs. AssertJ**

> Truth and AssertJ are very similar. This raises the question: Why did
> we create Truth? The reason is historical: AssertJ didn’t exist when
> we started Truth. By the time it was created, we’d begun migrating
> Google code to Truth, and we’d made some design decisions that would
> be difficult to retrofit onto AssertJ.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like what I am looking for. Do you know anywhere in the Android documentation that suggests to use AssertJ?

Comment: Or even explains it as an option?

Comment: I have updated the answer. According to android docs, Truth library is used.

Comment: So use Truth instead of AssertJ

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. You definitely earned the bounty. I'll award it when I am able to. There's a time limit on it.

Comment: Interestingly, the documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests#java has an import for Truth, but doesn't include it in the gradle dependencies. As you show the gradle dependency is shown in https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/test-setup.

Comment: See the Git repository for this example: https://github.com/android/testing-samples/blob/main/unit/BasicUnitAndroidTest/app/build.gradle. There defined dependency directly on Truth. But I think it is better to use Jetpack androidx.test.ext:truth

Comment: Thanks! This is good enough for me for now. It would be nice if the dependency was also listed on the Instrumented Tests training docs that you linked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use “assert” than “assertThat”.

```
private static boolean getBool(int i) {     return i == 0;   }
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // assert false; !will throw error
  assert true;// nothing will happen
  assert getBool(0);
  // assert getBool(1); !will throw error
}
```

Comment: Will you show a full example?

Comment: For example: assert false will throw error but assert true will not, so you can do similar things like assert 1==2 or assert getInt1()==getInt2()

Comment: `private static boolean getBool(int i) {
    return i == 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // assert false; !will throw error
    assert true;// nothing will happen
    assert getBool(0);
    // assert getBool(1); !will throw error
  }
  `

Comment: Please [edit] your answer instead of posting a comment.

Comment: To clarify, my question is about a test that uses JUnit and Hamcrest.

Comment: Both version of AssertThat were deprecated because assert is better to read

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The example code I copied from the Andriod documentation uses `assertThat()`. I'm trying to find which library to add as a dependency so I can import it.